Why is this question still closed?

I have a question about my Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange post: Is this a possible psychological/scientific reason for women on average not finding chests sexually attractive?

The question was closed as opinion-based, and is still opinion-based after edits.  What objective evidence can be provided to answer it?
Additional notes:

The question conflates sexual attraction with physical attraction.
The question is asking if something is a valid reason within science - this is a question about philosophy of science, not psychology.
The question is making a statement asking for validation, rather than asking a question - ie, "Here is my answer" rather than "What is the answer?"
Questions about "why" need to be clear on what level of interpretation is expected.  Since sexual characteristics are of evolutionary origin, it is not clear to me that this question belongs in psychology.SE, rather than biology.SE, though as-asked, it would be closed on any science stack.

A few questions you may want to review instead:

Are there studies on international differences on sexualization?: Breasts may be universally physically attractive, but not universally sexually attractive.
Why are (some) male humans sexually attracted to the breasts of female humans?: Sexual characteristics are basically the result of random mutations.


you see, that question (Why are (some) male humans . . .) is not closed. How my question was different than that? I am asking same in my other question about men's attraction for breasts. I even included lot of details also. So it feels like baised response to me.

It feels a bit absurd to me when you're giving me reference of a question which is also opinion based and much under researched than mine and yet not closed.
